# How do add an item at the top of MDList instead of at the bottom:

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I have an `MDList` and want to add items at the top of the list instead of at the bottom of the MDList, once a button is pressed. I have tried using the canvas `before` and `after`:

```
def report_test2(self):
    item2 = ThreeLineIconListItem(
        IconLeftWidget(
            icon="language-python"
        ), text="11",
        secondary_text="Secondary text here",
        tertiary_text="fit more text than usual"
    )

    container = self.ids.container
    container.add_widget(item2, canvas="after")
```

I have also tried changing the index position like so `container.add_widget(item2, 0)`, but nothing works. The documentation says that the index should default to 0 and get added at the top, but that doesn't seem to work.

I have also tried `container.add_widget(item2, -1)`, but it appears below the first added widget. If I clear the `MDList`, the first item is added, but it stays there and everything else is added below it. Think of the screen I want to create as a WhatsApp message list where the latest message appears at the top.
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Try that and check if works for you:

```py
def report_test2(self):
    item2 = ThreeLineIconListItem(
        IconLeftWidget(icon="language-python"),
        text="11",
        secondary_text="Secondary text here",
        tertiary_text="fit more text than usual"
    )
    container = self.ids.container
    if not container.children:
        container.add_widget(item2)
    else:
        container.insert_widget(0, item2)
```

Comment: I am getting this error `AttributeError: 'MDList' object has no attribute 'insert_widget'`.I guess insert widget is not available

Comment: I got it! `container.children` is a type of a list right? Could you please try that in `else` block instead `insert_widget`: `container.children[0:0] = [item2]`

Comment: That adds the widget at the bottom,but this time the widget is invisible.

Comment: `container.add_widget(item2)
    container.children = container.children[::-1]`This works but after adding at the top,it then adds to the bottom and continues adding top,then bottom continuously

Comment: Ive got.You create a list in the innit method.`self.widget_list`.Then you just add items at the index 0 of the list like so. `self.widget_list.insert(0, item1)`.After every insertion you call `self.update_container()`wchich is a method you will create that will loop through the list and add all the widgets.`container = self.ids.container
    container.clear_widgets()
    for widget in self.widget_list:
        container.add_widget(widget)`